# Python Django Restframework Password Validation does not work

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

At first I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66173855/password-validation-not-work-in-django-rest-framework) Post, but this doesn't work for me.

I have a Django Rest Framework Project. If I create a user through django directly I get errors like: [image]

But if I have a normal HTTP POST Request I get a normal 200 Response:

```json
{"email": "test@test.com", "response": "successfully registered new user.", "token": "3618d0c362dd66bbb093e1234b72901f9d74a905", "username": "haha"}
```

What is the problem? I also tried to build a custom validation for the password, but this isn't really what I want, because it is a great Django feature.

api/serializers.py

```py
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'password2',]

    def save(self):
        account = Account(
                email = self.validated_data['email'],
                username = self.validated_data['username'],
            )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match.'})
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
```

api/views.py

```py
@api_view(['POST', ])
def registration_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            account = serializer.save()
            data['response'] = 'successfully registered new user.'
            data['email'] = account.email
            data['username'] = account.username
            token = Token.objects.get(user = account).key
            data['token'] = token
        else:
            data = serializer.errors
            print(data)
        return Response(data)
```

Maybe you had the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you don't have a password validation. So it's very simple:

api/serializers.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
...
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'password2',]

    def save(self):
        account = Account(
                email = self.validated_data['email'],
                username = self.validated_data['username'],
            )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match.'})
->      validate_password(password)
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
```